# Adding the value parts of multiple HashMap into a new one

Tags: java, hashmap

I have three `HashMap<String, Integer>` where some keys may be present in two/three Maps.

I'm looking for a new `HashMap` that will combine all three in a new one where the value part will be a simple summation of all the values (where key is same).

I did that with `merge()` method,

```
Map<String, Integer> combine = new HashMap<>(map1);

map2.forEach((k, v) -> combine.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));
map3.forEach((k, v) -> combine.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));
```

Wondering, **How can I do it using Stream and/or Collection classes?**

Comment: You could just iterate over the entries.

Comment: What’s wrong with using merge?

Comment: @ManojBanik And I updated my comment ;)

Comment: Why would you **not** want to use the dedicated method for that?

Comment: Idiomatic, concise, efficient, unacceptable

Comment: What else if I need to do something else other than just 'sum'? This question is for learning purposes.

Comment: @ManojBanik whether you add or multiply or whatever, there’s still ultimately a BinaryOperator. Whether you pass it to merge or some other means (like my answer). Pick whatever is easiest to read and understand.

Comment: @Michael, I didn't ask for efficient one. Checking for alternatives other than plain iterating over the all HashMaps. I didn't expect those downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose:

```
Map<String, Integer> combine = Stream.of(map1, map2, map3)
    .map(Map::entrySet)
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, Math::addExact));
```

This does have the advantage of not modifying any of the maps. You approach would be a problem if map1 happens to be an unmodifiable map.

In general, avoid modification for achieving results that don’t require it, especially when such a side effect is unexpected.

Comment: @Michael oops, yes. Fixed now. Your proposal would work, but I like the elegance (and minuscule efficiency gain) of method references.

Comment: Not sure it's you can say it's more efficient since there's an additional intermediate operation, but yeah I like that way better too.

Comment: Still getting an error after the correction, "The method toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, Math::addExact) is undefined"

Comment: @ManojBanik `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;`